# docker-compose gives "ERROR: No such container" in mac sometimes

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose

I have 2 containers bind with docker-compose and when I run 'docker-compose' sometimes I get below error. But after few minutes when I do the same command this will work without any error.

**command:**

`docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up -d`

**error:**

```
ERROR: No such container: fc372eac40b072da029f4933317f184d0ca8b791970b505d3577d404f7d561ca
```

**docker ps -a :**

```
e34f8caed8c9 "docker-entrypoint.s…"

fc372eac40b0 "docker-entrypoint.s…"
```

Comment: It seems necessary to send the contents of `docker-compose.yml` file.

Comment: @rezshar contents or the context ?

Comment: @rezshar I added context but it didn't work. What do you mean by `contents` ?